# Is there a way to move all of certain item from a chest to inventory (or vice versa) in Bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What the title says. I've heard that in Minecraft Java you can shift and double-click to move all of one item from one container to another. But this doesnt appear to work in Bedrock edition. Is there a faster way than shift clicking each item/stack one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing on a controller, you can just press 'Y' to send all the items you are hovering over to your inventory/chest. If the items are all scattered, you can press 'A' two times on an item that you are hovering over, and then press 'Y'. Pressing 'A' twice takes all the items from a chest and inventory and puts it into one stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can do alt + double left click, if there is are items of the same block or item scattered around a chest or inventory, and they are stackable, it'll take those and put it up to a stack so you can move it. It also works if the same item is in both your inventory and chest to form up to a stack.

Comment: Does not work on bedrock 1.18.30